# JavaScript validation to check if a radio button is selected?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following form:

```
<form name="form" action="contact_submit.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()"
method="post">

<h2>Your Name</h2>
<input type="text" name="name">

<h2>Your E-mail Address</h2>
<input type="text" name="email" />
<h2>Phone Number</h2>
<input type="text" name="phone" />
<h2>Your Message</h2>
<input type="text" name="message" width="300px" height="200px" />
<h2>Preferred Contact?</h2>
<input type="radio" name="contact" value="email" id="email-pref">Email
<input type="radio" name="contact" value="phone" id="phone-pref"> Phone
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

After it is submitted, this JavaScript code is executed (in the validateForm() function):

```
if (document.getElementByID("email-pref").checked == true ||    
document.getElementByID("phone-pref").checked == true) {
alert("poopoo");
return false;
}
else {
alert("Contact preference must be filled out");
return false;
}
```

When I check one of the buttons, or none of the buttons, the form is still submitted, but all of the other validation statements seem to work. Is there a reason why it is not working, or could you suggest a better way of checking if at least one of the radio buttons are selected? Thanks.

Comment: Its `getElementById` not `getElementByID`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need *getElementById* (and hence can remove the ID attribute) if you reference the radio buttons by name. Pass a reference to the form to the listener using *this*:

```
<form ... onsubmit="return validateForm(this)" ...>
```

then in the function reference the radio group by name:

```
function validateForm(form) {

    var contacts = form.contact;

    if (contacts[0].checked || contacts[1].checked) {
      // one or the other is checked

    } else {
      // neither is checked
    }

    // more validation ...

}
```

However, when using radio buttons, you can make one checked by default and then you can be sure that one is checked when the form is posted:

```
  <input type="radio" name="contact" value="email" checked>Email
  <input type="radio" name="contact" value="phone"> Phone
```

Now you don't need to validate whether one is checked.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is case-sensitive. It's `getElementById` not `getElementByID`.

Comment: Oh, my mistake, I didn't think JavaScript was going to go all Sigmund Freud on me.